# Group an array by multiple fields

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an api response that looks like this:

```
people = [
    {
      name: 'John',
      surname: 'Doe',
      pet: {
          type: 'CAT',
          name: 'whiskers',
          age: 1
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'John',
      surname: 'Doe',
      pet: {
        type: 'DOG',
        name: 'Dexter',
        age: 4
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Jane',
      surname: 'Doe',
      pet: {
        type: 'CAT',
        name: 'Fluffy',
        age: 10
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'Jane',
      surname: 'Doe',
      pet: {
        type: 'CAT',
        name: 'Dennis',
        age: 3
      }
    }
  ]
```

I would like to translate it so that it looks like this (there are only ever two types of pet):

```
people = [
    {
        “name”: “John”,
        “surname”: “Doe”,
        “cats”: [
            {
                “name”: “whiskers”,
                “age”: 1
            }
        ],
        “dogs”: [
            {
                “name”: “Dexter”,
                “age”: 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        “name”: “Jane”,
        “surname”: “Doe”,
        “cats”: [
            {
                “name”: “Fluffy”,
                “age”: 10
            },
            {
                “name”: “Dennis”,
                “age”: 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm using angular 5. I need to be able to show a table similar to:

```
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Surname</th>
    <th>Cats</th>
    <th>Dogs</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let person of people">
    <td>{{person.name}}</td>
    <td>{{person.surname}}</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let cat of person.cats">name: {{cat.name}}, age: {{cat.age}} years</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let dog of person.dogs">name: {{dog.name}}, age: {{dog.age}} years</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried looping over building up a map as I went but I struggled to convert this back from a map to an array at the end. Also I was hoping there was a cleaner solution that I had missed:

```
const peopleMap = new Map;
this.people.forEach(person => {
  const key = person.name + '_' + person.surname;
  if (peopleMap[key]) {
    if (person.pet.type === 'CAT') {
      peopleMap[key].cats.push(new Pet(person.pet.name, person.pet.age));
    } else {
      peopleMap[key].dogs.push(new Pet(person.pet.name, person.pet.age));
    }
  } else {
    let cats: [Pet];
    let dogs: [Pet];
    if (person.pet.type === 'CAT') {
      cats.push(new Pet(person.pet.name, person.pet.age));
    } else {
      dogs.push(new Pet(person.pet.name, person.pet.age));
    }
    peopleMap[key] = new Person(person.name, person.surname, cats, dogs);
  }
});
```

Ideally I will be allowed to change the api so that this logic sits server side. In the meantime I would love to know how to do this.

Comment: If you are able to use a library interim while you sort out the API, [lodash](https://lodash.com/) has a [groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy) function that will handle this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this by reducing the array ([see Array.prototype.reduce][1]

[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce )

Basically, create an aggregate results array as you iterate through each (current) object in the "people" data. Check to see if an object with the person key exists. If they do, add the new pet to the appropriate pet array. Else, create a new person with the current pet.

Be sure to initialize the reduce function with an empty array (second argument when calling groupByPerson).

```
let people = [{name: 'John',surname: 'Doe',pet: {type: 'CAT',name: 'whiskers',age: 1}},{name: 'John',surname: 'Doe',pet: {type: 'DOG', name: 'Dexter',age: 4}},{name: 'Jane',surname: 'Doe',pet: {type: 'CAT',name: 'Fluffy',age: 10}},{name: 'Jane',surname: 'Doe',pet: {type: 'CAT',name: 'Dennis',age: 3}}];
function groupByPerson(data) {
        return data.reduce( function (results, current) {
            const key = current.name + "_" + current.surname;
            let matched = results.filter(r => r.key === key)[0];
            if (matched) {
                let petArray = (current.pet.type === "CAT") ? matched.cats : matched.dogs;
                petArray.push({name:current.pet.name, age:current.pet.age});
            }
            else { 
                let newPerson = {
                    key: key,
                    name: current.name,
                    surname: current.surname,
                    cats: [],
                    dogs: []
                }
                let petArray = (current.pet.type === "CAT") ? newPerson.cats : newPerson.dogs;
                petArray.push({name:current.pet.name, age:current.pet.age});
                results.push(newPerson); 
            }    
            return results;
        }, []); // initialize with empty array
    }
    const results = groupByPerson(people);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to summarize your data to an object. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array

```js
let people = [{name: 'John',surname: 'Doe',pet: {type: 'CAT',name: 'whiskers',age: 1}},{name: 'John',surname: 'Doe',pet: {type: 'DOG', name: 'Dexter',age: 4}},{name: 'Jane',surname: 'Doe',pet: {type: 'CAT',name: 'Fluffy',age: 10}},{name: 'Jane',surname: 'Doe',pet: {type: 'CAT',name: 'Dennis',age: 3}}];

let result = Object.values(people.reduce((c, {pet,...u}) => {
  let k = u.name + u.surname;             //Make a key using name and last name
  let {type,...p} = pet;                  //Deconstrct pet object
  type = type.toLowerCase();              //Make type lower case
  c[k] = c[k] || u;                       //Initiate if name does not exist
  c[k][type] = c[k][type] || [];          //Initiate if pet does not exist

  c[k][type].push(p);                     //Add the pet
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Fixing the answer to group:

First we create array with desired object structure

```
    var newPeople = people.map(function(item){
    var newPeople = {};
    newPeople.name = item.name;
    newPeople.surname = item.surname;
    var type = item.pet.type; 
    newPeople[type] = [];
    var petDetails = {
        name: item.pet.name,
        age: item.pet.age
    } 
    newPeople[type].push(petDetails);
    return newPeople;
});

/*Output: people = [{name: "John", surname: "Doe", CAT: Array(1)},
                    {name: "John", surname: "Doe", DOG: Array(1)}, 
                    {name: "Jane", surname: "Doe", CAT: Array(1)},
                    {name: "Jane", surname: "Doe", CAT: Array(1)}]*/
```

Now we will group them with below loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < newPeople.length; i++) {
    for(var j = i+1; j < newPeople.length;j++){
        var item = newPeople[i];
        var nextItem = newPeople[j];
        if(item.name === nextItem.name && item.surname === nextItem.surname) {
            var firstItemKeys = Object.keys(item);
            var nextItemKeys = Object.keys(nextItem);
            if(firstItemKeys[2] === nextItemKeys[2]) {
                item[firstItemKeys[2]].push(nextItem[nextItemKeys[2]][0]);
            } else {
                if (Array.isArray(item[nextItemKeys[2]])) {
                    item[nextItemKeys[2]].push(nextItem[nextItemKeys[2]][0]);
                } else {
                    item[nextItemKeys[2]] = [];
                    item[nextItemKeys[2]].push(nextItem[nextItemKeys[2]][0]);
                }
            }
            newPeople.splice(j,1);
            j--
        }   
    }       
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
newPeople = [{name: "John", surname: "Doe", CAT: Array(1), DOG: Array(1)},
{name: "Jane", surname: "Doe", CAT: Array(2)}]
```